# AWS EB url accessible behind ELB

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have setup a website using ElasticBeanstalk having ELB

Security Group for ELB is configured for 80 & 443 from 0.0.0.0/0

Security Group for EB is configured for 80 & 443 from ELB

Route53 A record has alias pointing to ELB & it works properly

Yet my site is getting access using EB URL http://custom-env.xx.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

How is it happening? To what does this URL points to?

Answer (score 0):

Your EB security group policies allows connection from any host on port 80 and 443. Since, you are directly hitting the EB url its accessible(I'm not sure its using ELB for load balancing, more on this later). A record in route 53 is just pointing the URL http://custom-env.xx.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/ to your EB application.

To verify whether ELB is indeed used, check the ELB configuration, its should be pointing to your application.

Comment: plz check my answer

Comment: yes, your configuration seems correct, this is how it should work. It's not necessary to have a elastic IP for your ELB. Even if you want to use custom domain name for your site, you can do that using Route53 without having an elastic IP.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help